# What exactly is deobfuscation

Tags: deobfuscation

Lately I have been hearing about code deobfuscation, I know that its something about formatting code to make it readable but, what im really looking for is what would it even look like(an example) why would I even do it, how can it be done. Just to clear it up, i do  fully understand the meaning of the word deobfuscation, improving things that are unclear or unreadable. What i don’t understand is the usage of this word in coding.

> my main goal is to get a full understanding about deobfuscation because google has really confused me

Comment: "Deobfuscation" = "remove obfuscations".

Comment: Ok, so what would that look like in coding, i mean code cant really be changed unless you modified it to be more readable for humans, so is that the meaning? Making things more readable for humans?

Comment: "why would I even do it" -- ask yourself the same question for obfuscation. Things like JavaScript and Python are sometimes obfuscated to protect perceived intellectual property. Deobfuscation aims to remove (or at least lessen) that protection.